# Create XML file in C# in special format

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want create a xml file using C# in this format

Can you can me?

I have one file and i want to create a file with this format. But I don't know with which of the classes in C# I can do it.

```
<table>
    <independentVar>aero/h_b-mac-ft</independentVar>
    <tableData>
          0             1.229       
          0.1           1.124       
          0.15          1.116       
          0.2           1.124       
          0.3           1.105       
          0.4           1.041       
          0.5           1.034       
          0.6           1.019       
          0.7           1.008       
          0.8           1.003       
          0.9           1.001       
          1             1           
          1.1           1 
    </tableData>
</table>
```

Comment: @SLaks Untrue! You can preserve whitespaces inside element. You can use the `xml:space` attribute to identify portions of documents where white space is considered important. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx

Also you can configure your parser to preserve whitespaces. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387014.aspx

Comment: Maybe your classmate can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282064/write-xmlfile-in-spacial-format

Comment: @achitaka-san, SLaks: XML preserves *any* whitespace, not just the whitespace inside elements. Whether certain whitespace nodes are declared "insignificant" by some application does not change the fact.

Answer (score 2):

In c# there are three most used classes to create XML:

1. [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
3. [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

It is difficult to give you a recommendation without knowing the context of your task.

One more challenge in your examlpe is to preserve whitespaces. Default XML settings trim / ignore whitepaces and line feeds, unless you specify some special attribute on XML element (See: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx)). Unfortunately some applications / readers ignore it anyway.

If you must read your xml with your own code you can configure your reader to preserve whitepaces in any case. See: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387014.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387014.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways of creating xml content in c#, `System.Xml.Linq` is one:

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx

```
var el = new XElement("Table", 
    new XElement("independentVar", "..."),
    new XElement("tableData", "..."));

el.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Good answer, but I expect to see another question that asks how to get some data structure to be converted to a tab-delimited format. The OP (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282064/write-xmlfile-in-spacial-format) may be fairly new to C#.